What's the difference between "indicator" and "indication"?
You know that both "indicator" and "indication" are nouns. How can I use them in a sentence, and regarding the meanings, what is the difference between them?

Example:
There are several key ....... that doctors look for in their diagnoses.

Should I use "indicators" or "indications" in the above blank?

A pregnancy test, or a covid test, is an "indicator," a thing designed to indicate. The lines or other way they show results are "indications."

This is complicated by an example in the medical field, where indication has a very specific meaning beyond its colloquial use, which is not at all synonymous with indicator.

An indicator is that which indicates something or can indicate something, focusing on the agent or do-er of the action of indicating.
An indication is an abstraction that refers to the result of the action of indicating.  The action of indicating results in a potential indication. An indication occurs when a perceiver observes an indicator indicating.
But you can use them interchangeably in some contexts as long as you include a prepositional phrase (indicator |  indication of something).

A cough indicates inflammation in the airway or lungs.
A cough is an indicator of inflammation in the airway or lungs.
Coughing is an indication of inflammation in the airway or lungs.

When using a sentence like the one you provided:

There are several key ....... that doctors look for in their diagnoses.

the focus would be on looking for that which has the ability to indicate, the indicator(s).  You can't look for an indication since it not an indication until it is observed.  But that doesn't stop people from saying things like "I'm looking for some indication that you're serious."  But doctors look to "key indicators" (things that can indicate) not for "key indications".

It's worth noting that in the particular field of medicine, indication has a very specific meaning which is not normally connoted in other contexts. An indication is a reason to use a particular drug or procedure. A doctor may indeed look for drug indications, for example by running some test and finding a result that allows some particular treatment course to be used. Doctors might look for indicators of disease, but when deciding treatment they are actually looking for reasons to justify their choice, which are indications.

And some treatments can be "contraindicated".
